# has_many :through with counter_cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It is my understanding that when defining a :counter_cache option it is to be specified on the model that includes the belongs_to declaration. So I am a little unsure of how to handle this when working with a has_may through association (as I believe that a belongs_to declaration is not used in this scenario):

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, :through => :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician, :counter_cache => appointment_count
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I wish to use the :counter_cache option to make finding the number of Patients belonging to a Physician more efficient.

```
myPhysician.patients.count
```

FYI: Rails 3.1

Cheers

Answer (score 33):

I'm not sure what kind of relationship you want. That example is similar to the one in the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association)

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, :through => :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, :through => :appointments
end
```

- A `Physician` has many `Appointments`, and has many `Patients`
- An `Appoinment` belongs to (has one) `Physician` and one `Patient`
- a `Patient` has many `Appointments` and many `Physicians`.

Regarding the :counter_cache option, according to the [belongs_to doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to):
If you want the number of `Patients` belonging to a `Physician` you would need:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician, :counter_cache => :patient_count
  belongs_to :patient
end
```

And you need to **write a migration to add the patient_count** column to the `Phyisicans` table.

However, **for has_many through relationships Rails 3.1 seems to automatically detect the counter_cache column**, so you don't have to specify it (remove `:counter_cache => :patient_count`). If you do specify it your counter will go up by two (this is very weird).

By the way, there seems to be **some problems with :counter_cache option in Rails 3.1**, as reported here:

- https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3903
- https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3085

With all of that in mind, maybe your best bet is to write your own count mechanism using callbacks.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: A little update: Automatic detection of counter cache for `has_many :through` has been removed from Rails: https://github.com/sgrif/rails/commit/f072980382db8cb64c09f63001ef805843db51c8

Comment: I don't understand how this answer got all these upvotes; this will increase the `Physician#patient_count` every time a new appointment is created, which is NOT what we want here. If a Patient has 5 appointments with the same Physician, the patient will be counted repeatedly as 5 patients, one for each appointment.

Answer (score 10):

I added a `counter_cache` to a `has_many :through` association on Rails 5.1, and the philosophy is the same as with `has_many`. Using the Physician, Appointment, Patient example:

1. add `patients_count` to the `physicians` table as an integer
2. add a counter cache to the the join model (appointment.rb): `belongs_to :physician, counter_cache: :patients_count`

**Note:** the answer above is correct, this answer just confirms that it works on Rails 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem, counting the number of records in a two-deep relationship. In your example, this would be the number of Patients for a Physician, as opposed to the number of Appointments. (e.g. don't count multiple appointments for one patient) I haven't tested the other solutions offered, but it appears they return the number of appointments.

I found no way to do this in Rails 4, primarily because there is no `belongs_to through:` option. After exhausting several fruitless approaches, I found `gem counter_culture`. This solved the problem easily, by defining a two-deep relationship to be counted:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :appointment
  counter_culture [:appointment, :physician]
end
```

Add a counter field to Physician with:

```
rails generate counter_culture Physician patients_count
```

And voila! You can now do easy activerecord queries like:

```
Physician.order(patients_count: 'DESC')
```

Answer (score 0):

I can also confirm that the method outlined by Ivica Lakatos works with Rails 6 for `has_many :through` relationships using a join model.

1. add patients_count to the physicians table as an integer
2. add a counter cache to the the join model (appointment.rb):
   `belongs_to :physician, counter_cache: :patients_count`