# reset_counters raise undefined method error, but works fine on similiar relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I try to add **counter_cache** to **User** to count owned **Projects**.

User has many projects, Project has many Users, but Project belongs to one of them.

So i wrote migration for adding extra count fields for counter_cache.

**Comments** has no trouble with `reset_counter`.

But `User.reset_counters user.id, :projects` raise **NoMethodError: undefined method `counter_cache_column' for nil:NilClass**.

Also counter_cache on projects is working OK. If i add extra project it will increment projects_count field, if i delete one - decrement.

**Models**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects, :through => :team_members
  has_many :team_members

class TeamMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :team_members
  has_many :team_members
  belongs_to :leader, :class_name => :User, :counter_cache => true

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
```

**Migration**

```
class AddCounters < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :users, :comments_count, :integer, :default => 0
    add_column :users, :projects_count, :integer, :default => 0 

    User.reset_column_information

    User.find_each do |user| 
      User.reset_counters user.id, :comments #all fine

      User.reset_counters user.id, :projects #raise NoMethodError
                                             #undefined method `counter_cache_column'
                                             #for nil:NilClass
    end
  end

  def down
    remove_column :users, :projects_count
    remove_column :users, :comments_count
  end
end
```

i tried to switch from `:counter_cache => true` to `:counter_cache => :projects_count`.

Same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should you not tell the models that they have many `:team_members` for the `:through` calls to work? Try adding:

```
has_many :team_members
```

to both the `User` and `Project` models.

---

**EDIT:** Looking at your setup more closely, it seems like the issue is that you're setting the counter cache on the `:leader` relation, which has no corresponding inverse on the `User` side. I'm not exactly sure which way you want it, but here is how I picture the options:

#### Option 1: Give the user a separate `:lead_projects` association

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lead_projects, :class_name => :Project, :inverse_of => :leader

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :leader, :class_name => :User, :counter_cache => :lead_projects_count, :inverse_of => :lead_projects
```

and a migration adding `:lead_projects_count` to the `:users` table.

#### Option 2: Make the `:projects_count` counter go through `TeamMembers`

As per [this similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189982/454094):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_members
  has_many :projects, :through => :team_members

class TeamMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => :projects_count
  belongs_to :project

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_members
  has_many :users, :through => :team_members
```

With this option, I think your current migration is sufficient.

---

Note: I'm just writing code as I go here; please comment if I got the syntax wrong so I can edit my answer for future readers.

Comment: Looks like a accepted answer, will give it a shot today, yes there are `has_many :team_members` in both Project and User models i just forgot to add these lines