# Rails, how to avoid the "N + 1" queries for the totals (count, size, counter_cache) in associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, relationship

I have a these models:

```
class Children < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tickets
    has_many :movies, through: :tickets
end


class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tickets
    has_many :childrens, through: :tickets
    belongs_to :cinema
end


class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :movie, counter_cache: true
    belongs_to :children
end


class Cinema < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :movies, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :childrens, through: :movies
end
```

What I need now is in the page of "Cinemas" I wanna print the sum (count, size?) of the childrens just for the movies of that cinemas, so I wrote this:

- **in the cinemas_controller.rb**:

`@childrens = @cinema.childrens.uniq`

- **in the cinemas/show.html.erb**:

`<% @childrens.each do |children| %><%= children.movies.size %><% end %>`

but obviously I have bullet gem that alert me for Counter_cache and I don't know where to put this counter_cache because of different id for the movie.

**And also without the counter_cache what I have is not what I want because I want a count for how many childrens in that cinema taking them from the tickets from many days in that cinema.**

How to?

**UPDATE**

If in my view I use this code:

```
<% @childrens.each do |children| %>
  <%= children.movies.where(cinema_id: @cinema.id).size %>
<% end %>
```

gem bullet don't say me anything and every works correctly.

**But I have a question**: this way of querying the database is more heavy because of the code in the views?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might help you.

```
@childrens_count = @cinema.childrens.joins(:movies).group("movies.children_id").count.to_a
```

Comment: Can you explain it better?

Comment: @JohnSam. Oh sorry there is issue in grouping. Please change movies.children_id to ticket.children_id. The output will contain sum of the movies for each children. In view part you can use this output array to display the data.

Comment: Yes, I corrected it. What would be interesting is how to display result in my grid (list, index.html.erb).

Comment: You can use similarly like this,  <% @count.each.do |cnt| %> <%= cnt %> <% end%>

Comment: maybe it's better to end with `.count.to_h` (**to_h**)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [includes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) to load all associations ahead of time. For example:

```
@childrens = @cinema.childrens.includes(:movies).uniq
```

This will load all of the children's movies in the controller, preventing the view from needing access to the database in your loop.

Comment: yes, but I need totals. Also with includes I have the bullet gem error for counter_cache and a lot of queries.

Comment: Ah, I see. Perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9189982/1507845) will give you what you need.

Comment: I don't think so. Because is not what I need. I already have the counter_cache.

Answer (score 5):

You might agree, that the number of movies belongs to a child equals the number of tickets they bought.
That's why you could just cache the number of tickets and show it on the cinemas#show.
You can even create a method to make it more clear.

```
class Children < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets
  has_many :movies, through: :tickets

  def movies_count
    tickets.size
  end
end

class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :movie, counter_cache: true
  belongs_to :children, counter_cache: true
end

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cinema
  has_many :tickets
  has_many :childrens, through: :tickets
end

class Cinema < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :movies, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :childrens, through: :movies
end
```

And then:

```
<% @childrens.each do |children| %><%= children.tickets.size %><% end %>
```

Or

```
<% @childrens.each do |children| %><%= children.movies_count %><% end %>
```

But if you want to show the number of tickets for every movie, you definitely need to consider the following:

```
@movies = @cinema.movies
```

Then:
   `<% @movies.each do |movie| %><%= movie.tickets.size %><% end %>`

Since you have `belongs_to :movie, counter_cache: true`, `tickets.size` won't make a count query.
And don't forget to add `tickets_count` column. [More about counter_cache...](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

P.S. Just a note, according to conventions we name a model as Child and an association as Children.

Comment: Dear @Ihar Drozdov, I can't agree with you because I need count of tickets for each movie, not totals of all movies!

Comment: Nope. You still don't understand my question. Please see the edited part of my question. I need the count of total tickets of each children for that movie in the cinema's show page. Without each query for each children. Is it more clear now the question?

Answer (score 5):

Actually is much more simpler than the remaining solutions

You can use `lazy loading`:

In your controller:

```
def index
  # or you just add your where conditions here
  @childrens = Children.includes(:movies).all 
 end
```

In your view `index.hml.erb`:

```
<% @childrens.each do |children| %>
  <%= children.movies.size %>
<% end %>
```

The code above won't make any extra query if you use `size` but if you use `count` you will face the `select count(*)` n + 1 queries

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a little ActiveRecord plugin some time ago but haven't had the chance to publish a gem, so I just created a gist:

https://gist.github.com/apauly/38f3e88d8f35b6bcf323

Example:

```
# The following code will run only two queries - no matter how many childrens there are:
#   1. Fetch the childrens
#   2. Single query to fetch all movie counts
@cinema.childrens.preload_counts(:movies).each do |cinema|
  puts cinema.movies.count
end
```

---

To explain a bit more:

There already are similar solutions out there (e.g. https://github.com/smathieu/preload_counts) but I didn't like their interface/DSL. I was looking for something (syntactically) similar to active records `preload` (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/preload) method, that's why I created my own solution.

To avoid 'normal' N+1 query issues, I always use `preload` instead of `joins` because it runs a single, seperate query and doesn't modify my original query which would possibly break if the query itself is already quite complex.

Comment: Your answer seems interesting a lot! What do you think of this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/31313129/4412054), I modified a bit (`@childrens_count = @cinema.childrens.group("tickets.children_id").size`) for use it in my case. It just works! Your solution how does it differ?

Comment: Oops, it seems that I just posted another answer instead of editing the original one, so I just deleted the older version.

Comment: Can you answer my question?

Comment: The approach is basically the same

Comment: the trick is to use `.size` when using lazy loading just like in my answer

Answer (score 0):

In You case You could use something like this:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :movie, counter_cache: true
    belongs_to :children
end
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tickets
    has_many :childrens, through: :tickets
    belongs_to :cinema
end
class Children < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tickets
    has_many :movies, through: :tickets
end
class Cinema < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :movies, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :childrens, through: :movies
end


@cinema = Cinema.find(params[:id])
@childrens = Children.eager_load(:tickets, :movies).where(movies: {cinema_id: @cinema.id}, tickets: {cinema_id: @cinema.id})


<% @childrens.each do |children| %>
  <%= children.movies.count %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Ticket belongs_to the movie, not to the cinema.

Comment: And, overall, your code doesn't work. I still have a lot of queries, one for each children.

Comment: I wrote `You could use something like this`. I don;t know how You created tables via migrations... In my project good is "eager_load" and it is work properly. But in Your project it is may be "joins" or "include" -- as relitable to Your DB schemas... Main idea -- You make with joins "big table" where You filter movies and  tickets which owned by certain cinema. And as next You count how much movies have certain children.. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach using `counter_cache` is in right direction.

But to take full advantage of it, let's use children.movies as example, you need to add `tickets_count` column to `children` table firstly.

execute `rails g migration addTicketsCountToChildren tickets_count:integer`,

then `rake db:migrate`

now every ticket creating will increase tickets_count in its owner(children) by 1 automatically.

then you can use

```
<% @childrens.each do |children| %>
  <%= children.movies.size %>
<% end %>
```

without getting any warning.

if you want to get children count by movie, you need to add `childrens_count` to `movie` table:

```
rails g migration addChildrensCountToMovies childrens_count:integer
```

then `rake db:migrate`

ref:

http://yerb.net/blog/2014/03/13/three-easy-steps-to-using-counter-caches-in-rails/

please feel free to ask if there is any concern.

Comment: Dear @Chuanpin, what I need is not what you wrote. I need to find a way to not have a N+1 query using this code in my cinema/show.html.erb. Because I want to show a list of childrens taked by ticket for that cinema (in many days) and for each children in that list I want a count for how many ticket. Read the edited part of my question, please.

Answer (score -1):

Based on [sarav answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31313129/3002847) if you have a lot of things(requests) to count you can do:

in controller:

`@childrens_count = @cinema.childrens.joins(:movies).group("childrens.id").count.to_h`

in view:

```
<% @childrens.each do |children| %>
   <%= @childrens_count[children.id] %>
<% end %>
```

This will prevent a lot of sql requests if you train to count associated records