# Rails counter cache with has_many: :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, counter-cache

I have a Part model that `has_many :images, through: :gallery` and I would like to implement `counter_cache` to store the images count of a part. This is my setup.

Part

```
has_one :gallery, dependent: :destroy
has_many :images, through: :gallery
```

Gallery

```
belongs_to :part
has_many :images
```

Image

```
belongs_to :gallery
```

I can do `@part.images` to fetch images of a part and now I would like to cache images count so I can do `@part.images.size` or even order parts by `images_count`. I would normally do this using `counter_cache: true` on a `belongs_to` side but how do I do this in this case? Is it possible?

Comment: How about those answers - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991118/has-many-through-with-counter-cache ? The problem is similar to yours

Comment: Thanx, the second answer in that thread helped me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from the comment I managed to solve it by doing it like this:

- add images_count column to Parts and update counters in the migration

```
class AddImagesCountToParts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :parts, :images_count, :integer, default: 0, null: false

    Part.find_each { |part| Part.reset_counters(part.id, :images) }
  end
end
```

- add counter_cache: :images_count to Gallery

```
belongs_to :part, counter_cache: :images_count
```

Comment: That will just count the galleries.

Comment: No. I verified this, `part.images.size == part.images_count`